# How to make a synchronous method behave asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a method in Java which, after setting the required fields from the database, makes a web service call. However this method is made synchronous and when we run a batch which calls this method on a different case id (around 10000+ cases), it takes more than one day. I have no clue why this was made synchronous so how can I make this method call behave asynchronously?

```
public synchronized void sendNotice(CaseKey caseKey, Long communicationId) {

// calling data from database

// setting parameters for webserice 

// make a webservice call

// this code will be called 470 times

}
```

Comment: Change the number on line 5 to '4', and you're good!  (aka: how can we possibly say anything about your code if you don't show any?)

Comment: without any code, who knows. The only obvious answer would be "by making it asynchronous instead of synchronous".

Comment: Its in VMware on client machine.I cannot paste it

Comment: An example should help...

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your web service calls in `Callable` objects, and execute them via an appropriate `ExecutorService`.  It might look something like this:

```
public class WSResult {
    public int getResultProp1() {
       ...
    }
}

public class WSCall implements Callable<WSResult> {
    public WSCall(int param1, String param2) {
        ...
    }

    public WSResult call() {
        // perform WS call
        return new WSResult(...);
    }
}

public class SomeClass {
    // ...

    public void driver() {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(WS_CAPACITY);
        List<Future<WSResult>> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
            results.add(service.submit(new WSCall(... parameters ...)));
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination();

        // ... do something with the results ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute the code in an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<?> f = es.submit(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendNotice(caseKey, communicationId);
    }
});
```

You obtain a `Future<?>` representing the pending completion of the task.

Answer (score -1):

You can't make the method behave asynchronously if you cannot change the code. 
The only way overcome this is to run your test cases from multiple JVMs.